# (select [amount] from [payment] where ([payment_account] = 'Confirmation Deposit') and ([action] = 'Received') and ([amount] = '95'))

Tags: sql

Getting a syntax error can't figure it out.  Please Help! Thanx

Comment: Remove `(` at the start of query & `)` at the end of query, then its fine.

Comment: Please put your **actual** question in the question body, not the title. Apart from that: square brackets are invalid in an identifier in "SQL" - the standard query language.

Comment: I don't have a crystal ball to see your screen. What is the error, what are you trying to do? Please read [ask]

Answer (score 0):

```
 select amount
   from payment
  where payment_account = 'Confirmation Deposit'
    and action = 'Received'
    and amount = '95'
```